# system.net.http not found in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin application I need to implement the web-service using HttpClient.

So I create the test project & test the web-service - No problem here.

**My code:**

```
public async Task<string> registrationRequest()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string response = await client.GetStringAsync(registrationURL);

        return response;
    }
```

**My problem:**

After test the testing application I use the same code in my live project
system.net.http not found error.

HttpClient - not resolved.

In my test project I am not install any Nuget packages.

I just use the

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

But in my live project this import return error.

Anyone help me out..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to install the [Microsoft.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) nuget package in your PCL and platform-specific projects.

Comment: Thanks problem solved.. 
one doubt - In my test project I am not install this.. How this works in my test project?

Comment: Is it possible you were using shared code instead of PCL for your test project?

Comment: No bro.. i am use the code in PCL. In PCL this import working without any library installation.